# Connection get closed after some time

Tags: web-services, blackberry, blackberry-eclipse-plugin, blackberry-jde, j2mepolish

I have used below code for internet connection

```
HttpConnection httpConn = null;
DataOutputStream dataOS = null;
redemptionUrl = redemptionUrl+ ";deviceside=true";
httpConn = (HttpConnection) Connector.open(redemptionUrl);

httpConn.setRequestProperty("User-Agent",
"Profile/MIDP-1.0, Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "Keep-Alive");
httpConn.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
httpConn.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
dataOS = (DataOutputStream) httpConn.openDataOutputStream();
dataOS.flush();
dataOS.close();
DataInputStream dataIS = (DataInputStream) httpConn
.openDataInputStream();
int ch;
sb = new StringBuffer();
System.out.println("%%%% Me here 4 sb is ::" + sb.toString());
while ((ch = dataIS.read()) != -1) {
sb.append((char) ch);
}
// Respeonse
// -------------------------------------------------------------
System.out.println("sb.toString()::" + sb.toString());
String responseData = sb.toString();
dataIS.close();
httpConn.close();
```

After some time connection is disconnected. what's wrong ,can any one help

Comment: 1). in how many time connection will close...??
2). When connection will disconnected "between sending data" or "else"...?

Comment: I am using web service in my app.I am able to login into the app and gets response from webservice in form of all user data and then after that get disconnects after that when I send request its shows Request Timed out

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
public class HttpPostRetriver extends Thread{
private String _url;
private StringBuffer _postData;
private byte[] _data=new byte[512];
private HttpConnection _httpConnection;
private OutputStream os;
private InputStream is;

public HttpPostRetriver(String url) {
    _url = url+UrlSuffix.updataConnectionSuffix();
    try {
      _httpConnection = (HttpConnection)Connector.open(_url);
    } catch(Exception e) {
    }
}

public String postData() {
     try {
        _httpConnection.setRequestMethod(HttpConnection.POST);
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("User-Agent","Profile/MIDP-2.0 Configuration/CLDC-1.0");
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Language", "en-US");
        _httpConnection.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
        os = _httpConnection.openOutputStream();

        int rc = _httpConnection.getResponseCode();
        if(rc == HttpConnection.HTTP_OK) {
              is = _httpConnection.openInputStream();
              is.read(_data);
        } else {
          _data = null;
        }
   } catch(Exception e) {
       //exception
   }
   return (new String(_data));
}
}
```

Try this code .........